# what is used for binary interfaces in javascript -Uint8Array or ArrayBuffer or custom thingy?

Tags: javascript

## Context

I am trying to make a JavaScript library for basic reusable binary actions, like:

- generate random bytes sequence
- concat 2 or more bytes sequences
- getting slice of bytes sequence
- checking bytes sequence for equality
- sequentially writing values like bytes sequences, numbers of all sorts (from uint8 to int64) to pre-allocated and "allocated on demand") memory.
- sequentially reading values as described above from memory
- encoding text to memory fragments via utf8 and back
- encoding memory fragment to base64 or base64Url and back
- getting `Uint8Array` or `ArrayBuffer` (Uint8Array) from memory fragment, if used own concept of memory fragments

I trying to implement it in a way it can be used either in Node or in browser.
Generally cross-environment approach seems to work, via webpack and a testing webpage.

In that context, memory fragment is something that implements

```js
export class MemoryFragment {
   readonly length: number;
   readonly buffer:ArrayBuffer;
   readonly dataView: DataView;
   readonly bytes: Uint8Array;

   //constructor cropped, it does not matter here for discussion

   clone():MemoryFragment;
   concat(other:IMemoryFragment):MemoryFragment;
   slice(start?:number, length:number):MemoryFragment;
   
   static generateRandom(length):MemoryFragment;
   static allocate(length):MemoryFragment;
   static fromText(str:string):MemoryFragment;
   static fromBase64(encoded:string):MemoryFragment;
   static fromBase64Url(encoded:string):MemoryFragment;

   toText():string;
   toBase64():string;
   toBase64Url():string;
 
   static fromBuffer(buf:ArrayBuffer):MemoryFragment;
   static fromBytes(bytes:Uint8Array):MemoryFragment;
   static resolve(memoryRef:MemoryFragment|ArrayBuffer|Uint8Array):MemoryFragment;

}
```

What I concerned about, that when it was implemented using literal concept of memory fragments, like `MemoryFragment` class or `IMemoryFragment` it complicate things dramatically. Like, as soon as you need to interact with some other library or API beyond memory fragments' "ecosystem" it becomes painful to use.

So, after some experimenting I come to conclusion that best ways to go are either `Uint8Array` or `ArrayBuffer` used as "memory fragments" directly and returned to results across API.

## Question

What is better to use as "memory fragments" in context of interoperability with other packages and web & Node API:

- `ArrayBuffer`
- `Uint8Array`

I want to get best interoperability and ease of use with API like `window.crypto.subtle`, `window.crypto.getRandomValues`, and their node-specific counterparts from `node:crypto` module, and other Node and browser APIs and packages for binary IO.
I concerned mostly about easy of use, not memory consumption.

Essentially, ease of use means not need to apply some adaptation of values via getting some property or calling some converting function too often.

If I have to type something like `memory.buffer` or `memory.bytes` too much, it surely sign of a poor interoperability between API and my library.

## PS

So far, the browser API uses `ArrayBuffer` everywhere for results and accepts various "buffer-friendly objects like typed arrays who have `buffer` property, `bytesOffset` and `bytesLength` property, as inputs.

But what about other packages for in-browser binary IO?
I suspect the most Node packages still use `Buffer` but it is "relative"/"sibling" (actually subclass of) `Uint8Array` these days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are pretty trivial to convert from one to another so I wouldn't mind too much.

In general, I would use `Uint8Array` for everything that is specifically a *sequence of bytes*, i.e. where the user will interact with the individual byte values, whereas an `ArrayBuffer` represents *arbitrary encoded binary data* that the user typically will not/should not interact with (or knows how to decode themselves, if there is some complex structure in the data).

But what's more important is that `Uint8Array` is a *view* on a buffer. The buffer might be shared with other views, and the views may represent only a *slice* of the buffer. So if your API offers a method that reads from or writes to a user-provided memory location, use an `Uint8Array` - this might allow to avoid some copying. (Though, "out parameters" that get written into are harder to use than return values, so unless performance matters, better return a new value - or provide both functionality).

As for inputs, you can make your API easier to use by overloading it so that simply both `Uint8Array`s (or really any buffer view/typed array) and `ArrayBuffer`s are accepted, possibly even integer `Array`s.